# How can I create additional user in influxdb2 with a docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb-2

I am able to run a `docker-compose.yml` that starts an influxdb2 and configures with a admin user, org and bucket. My problem is that I am not able to create an additional user (without admin privileges) via the `docker-compose.yml`.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint.

```
docker-compose.yml:
`version: "3.5"
services:

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb2
    volumes:
      - influxdb-storage:/etc/influxdb2:rw
      - influxdb-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=adminuser
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=adminpassword
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=myOrg
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=myBucket
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=randomTokenValue
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    restart: unless-stopped`
```

I tried adding an entrypoint to somehow run the following command:

```bash
influx user create -n john -p user -o myOrg
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `influxdb:latest` image is described in the following repository: [influxdata-docker/influxdb/2.6/](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/tree/64a63b05b198b6a45176462814d3f35677625415/influxdb/2.6)

If you check these files you will see that user is created inside `entrypoint.sh` script in `setup_influxd()` function, called from `main() -> init_influxd()`.

There is a `run_user_scripts()` function which runs user-defined scripts on startup, if directory specified by `${USER_SCRIPT_DIR}` variable exists:

```bash
# Allow users to mount arbitrary startup scripts into the container,
# for execution after initial setup/upgrade.
declare -r USER_SCRIPT_DIR=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

...

# Execute all shell files mounted into the expected path for user-defined startup scripts.
function run_user_scripts () {
    if [ -d ${USER_SCRIPT_DIR} ]; then
        log info "Executing user-provided scripts" script_dir ${USER_SCRIPT_DIR}
        run-parts --regex ".*sh$" --report --exit-on-error ${USER_SCRIPT_DIR}
    fi
}
```

I think you could use this functionality to do the additional steps. But probably you'll need to guard against running these steps twice.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks a lot for the hint. I will try this these days.